# WordPress is redirecting category links to posts

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a WordPress site and after messing with permalinks - some of the categories are redirecting to blog posts. I have tried erasing the .htaccess file and editing the .htaccess file ... also have tried returning the settings to default & then changing them back to what I want ... which is for posts to follow the hierarchy of %category%/%postname% .... and I have set the category to blank or .

When I click the subcategory (clarifying that it is a subcategory link having this issue) link it goes to one of my posts instead of the category page.